# Printer Job Always 'Stopped'

Tags: 12.10, gnome, printing, lexmark, gnome-control-center

I am running Ubuntu 12.10/ GNOME 3 Remix (amd64). When I try to print anything from my Lexmark S605 Interact, the job automatically stops under job status.

I might be missing something really obvious, and I'm quite new to this, so if there's anything else you need to know, tell me.

Also, if anyone else uses this printer, how did you install it? I've tried both with and without the Lexmark software, available from their website, and both with USB and with the network.

I'm pretty sure that I have all of the necessary programs installed (or have had at one point) and have tried with `sudo`, so I don't think it's permissions, but I'm not sure.

Anyways, thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

- Click on Dash
- Search for **Printers**
- Right click on the printer that's shown
- Make sure that **Enabled** is checked

Comment: I can't right clock on it. Maybe it's because I'm using Gnome? But the printer is turned ON if that's the same thing.

Comment: I understand about the printer being turned on, but it needs to be Enabled via the method I've said.  Is it possibly you can go into Unity and try it that way?  Failing that, I'm stuck for an answer to help.

Comment: I checked the printer attributes and it said the printer-status-message as printer filter failed. I've printer ENABLED.